# Pinescript: How to set a plotshape label below/above the Bar with some distance?

Tags: pine-script

How to set a plotshape label below/above the Bar with some distance? Like the screenshot below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiK9Q.png)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `\n`

Example:

`plotchar(dcc, title="Dark cloud cover", char="☁", location=location.top, color=color.orange, text=".\n.\n.\Dcc")`

`plotshape(test, title="test",style=shape.circle, location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, text="test\n\n")`

Comment: Thanks, that was actually a very good share

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

ema1 = ema(close, 13)
ema2 = ema(close, 50)

condition = crossover(ema1, ema2)

plot(ema1)
plot(ema2)

// 
atr_dist = atr(14) //atr distance
perc_dist = input(2.0, "Distance in %:") //% distance

if condition
    // label.new(bar_index, high + atr_dist, "Above", style=label.style_label_down, color = color.green)
    label.new(bar_index, high + high *perc_dist /100, "Above", style=label.style_label_down, color = color.green) //or use % as distance
    // label.new(bar_index, high - atr_dist, "Below", style=label.style_label_up, color = color.red)
    label.new(bar_index, low - low *perc_dist /100, "Below", style=label.style_label_up, color = color.red) //or use % as distance
```

[image]